# How to dynamically add jar to classpath in java

Tags: java

So, I won't go into detail into why I can't add it normally through an IDE, but I need to dynamically add a local jar to my classpath at runtime, how would I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime

Comment: Checkout System.load and System.loadLibrary

Answer (score 0):

Just use [gradle](http://gradle.org), you can use local dependencies like this

```
compile files('lib/ojdbc6.jar')
```